# how to prevent element on Router to refresh pages preventing alert to pop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router, page-refresh

I have some conditions in my Router (if a user is active or not, etc). 
The routing works great except when I'm on the login page, even if I stay on the page, the page refreshes preventing the alert to pop (if the password is wrong for example).

How can I prevent the page to refresh if I stay on this page ?

My code :

```
const { user, loading } = useUser();
  const unauthorizedCategory = ["CO", "CC"];

  if (loading && !user) return <></>;

  if (user?.activeUser) {
    switch (location.pathname) {
      case LOGIN:
        return <Navigate to={HOME} replace={true} state={{ from: location }} />;
      case P1_SURVEY_PROFILE:
        return <Navigate to={HOME} replace={true} state={{ from: location }} />;
      case PROFILE_MANAGEMENT_STYLE:
        if (unauthorizedCategory.includes(user?.account?.category?.categoryCode)) {
          navigate(-1);
        } else {
          return <Outlet />;
        }
      case SITUATIONS_ANNUAL_INTERVIEW:
        if (unauthorizedCategory.includes(user?.account?.category?.categoryCode)) {
          navigate(-1);
        } else {
          return <Outlet />;
        }
      case SITUATIONS_REFOCUSING_INTERVIEW:
        if (unauthorizedCategory.includes(user?.account?.category?.categoryCode)) {
          navigate(-1);
        } else {
          return <Outlet />;
        }
        break;
      default:
        return <Outlet />;
    }
  } else {
    console.log("1");

    if (user?.account?.firstConnection === true && location.pathname === P1_SURVEY_PROFILE) {
      console.log("3");
      return <Outlet />;
    } else if (
      location.pathname === LOGIN ||
      location.pathname === RENEW_PASSWORD ||
      location.pathname === CHANGE_PASSWORD ||
      location.pathname === RESET_PASSWORD
    ) {
      console.log("4");
      return <Outlet />;
    } else {
      return (
        <Navigate
          to={user?.account?.firstConnection === true ? P1_SURVEY_PROFILE : LOGIN}
          replace
          state={{ from: location }}
        />
      );
    }
  }
};

const Router = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path={CGU} element={<CguPage />} />
      <Route element={<ProtectedHandler />}>
        <Route path={LOGIN} element={<Signin />} />
        <Route path={RENEW_PASSWORD} element={<RenewPasswordPage />} />
        <Route path={CHANGE_PASSWORD} element={<ChangePasswordPage />} />
        <Route path={RESET_PASSWORD} element={<ResetPasswordPage />} />
        <Route path={P1_SURVEY_PROFILE} element={<P1SurveyProfile />} />
        <Route element={<Layout />}>
          <Route path="/*" element={<AppRoutes />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

In the case of a wrong password, I switch between console.log 1 and 4.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to prevent a post back when you submit your form. In your form handler `event.preventDefault()` should fix it.

Comment: I'm using React hook form and even with event.preventDefault() it does not seem to work.
I still have the page refreshing.